# How to return 2 response object in second SwitchMap and consume in subscribe method

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, typescript-typings

```
.pipe(
     switchMap(x => { return this.clientService.A(); }), 
     filter(firstResp => Helpers.IsNotNull(firstResp)),
     switchMap(firstRep => { return this.clientService.B(firstResp.someProp); }),
 ).subscribe( 

//Want to access response of both services in subscribe method.
 
);
```

First SwitchMap is returning response of service **A**,which is going in second SwitchMap. In this Subscribe method I need to consume both swithMap responses. How can i achieve that?

**Note-** Both service response type is diff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest the pipes:

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.clientService.A()),
    filter(firstResp => Helpers.IsNotNull(firstResp)),
    switchMap(firstRep => this.clientService.B(firstResp.someProp)
        .pipe(map(b => [firstRep, b]))),
 ).subscribe(([a, b]) => {
     // stuff
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted.
Is It Possible to return both response in second switchMap like below-
`code`   switchMap(firstRep => { 
let second Resp = this.clientService.B(firstResp.someProp);
return of(firstResp,secondResp) }).
subscribe(resp=>{ //access resp.firstResp
//resp.secondResp});

Comment: It looks to me that the above code is doing this for you. The `([a,b]) => {...}`  is giving you access to both `a` (firstResp) and `b` (secondResp).

Comment: yes I have received my answer. But just wanted to know that why my code mentioned in above comment would not work.

Comment: For 2 values nesting works well, but for multiple values it start to feel like a code smell.  I was involved in this [article](https://thisisuntapped.com/articles/aggregating-rxjs-requests.html) that discusses the possible approaches in more depth.

Comment: @sumitsharma if you put the responses through a `switchMap` to `of`, the subscription callback executes twice: once for the first response, and a separate second time with the second response; So you won't have access to both together. You may want that if you want to treat both responses the same way. If you _do_ want that the way you showed won't work because you're returning an observable with secondResp instead of the value of that observable. A correction would be my answer but instead of `map(b => [firstRep, b])` use `switchMap(b => of(firstRep, b))`